# Is it right to combine past and present in the same sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, tenses

I am defining an instrument but am not sure if it is correct to combine past and present tense at the same time:

> Ssdd is the first ever instrument, launched in 1998, which was
>   specifically 
>        designed to measure the gmn at Ka-band at global scale.

Is the usage of **is** and **was** correct?

Comment: The example may be a bit unsuitable here, but yes, in appropriate cases, each clause can have its own tense, so to speak.

Comment: Some of the Qs in the "RELATED" box at right may also interest you. Esp., https://english.stackexchange.com/q/174751/14666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not right to mix tenses. The sentence is in any case somewhat muddled. I would reword it thus:

> Ssdd, launched in 1998, was the first instrument specifically designed to measure the GMN, at Ka-band, at the global scale.

Comment: Why do you think not?

Comment: I used to think it wasn't correct to mix tenses, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: In that rewording, two articles (before *GMN* and *global*) and the commas around *at Ka-band* are superfluous.  Perhaps instead write  “Ssdd, launched in 1998, was the first instrument specifically designed to measure Ka-band GMN at global scale.”